# How to select shipments that have one activity but doesn't have another one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Simplified version of a table

**`Table ActivityHistory:`**

```
ActivityHistoryid(PK) | ShipmentID | ActivityCode | Datetime  
1                     | 1          | CodeA        |  
2                     | 1          | CodeB        |  
3                     | 1          | CodeC        |  
4                     | 2          | CodeA        |  
5                     | 3          | CodeA        |  
6                     | 3          | CodeB        |  
7                     | 4          | CodeC        |
```

This table contains the list of activities that occurred to given shipments.
**Task:** I need to select shipments(shipment ids) that has `"CodeA"` and doesn't have a `"CodeC"` activity.
In this example, shipment id 2 and 3 will match the criteria.
**Table Shipment:** (ShipmentID(PK), other shipment related columns)

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      ActivityHistoryid INT
    , ShipmentID INT
    , ActivityCode VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (ActivityHistoryid, ShipmentID, ActivityCode)
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 'CodeA'),
    (2, 1, 'CodeB'),
    (3, 1, 'CodeC'),
    (4, 2, 'CodeA'),
    (5, 3, 'CodeA'),
    (6, 3, 'CodeB'),
    (7, 4, 'CodeC') 

SELECT * 
FROM @temp t
WHERE ActivityCode = 'CodeA'
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM @temp t2
        WHERE t2.ActivityCode = 'CodeC'
            AND t2.ShipmentID = t.ShipmentID
    )
```

**Output:**

```
ActivityHistoryid ShipmentID  ActivityCode
----------------- ----------- --------------------
4                 2           CodeA
5                 3           CodeA
```